# django-cms: ImportError: No module named cms

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-cms

A while ago I worked on a local django-cms project everything worked fine but now when I run `python manage.py runserver` command i get an ImportError. The only thing i did was to rename the directory where my django project was in. This happens many times when i'm working on django-cms projects (Never when i built sites with django on my own). I'm using django 1.7.1 and python 2.7. Can someone tell my why this happening and how to fix that?
Here my Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named cms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtualenv has an absolute Path, because i moved my Project to another location it was broken. I found out the actual Path by typing `printenv` then i typed `virtualenv envname` to change it to the actual location.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using virtualenv. activate virtualenv first.

```
source env_directory/bin/activate
```

or `workon envname` if you are using virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: don't forgot on that :(